# How to limit the posts

Tags: wp-query

I have a new question, how can I limit the amount of posts coming out of this query? I only need 7

```
<?php
$newsposts = new WP_Query('cat=restaurant');
if ( is_front_page()) { 
    echo '<h3 class="member-review">Latest Restaurants</h3>
    <div id="extra">';
    if ($newsposts->have_posts()) : while ($newsposts->have_posts()) : $newsposts->the_post();
        echo '<div class="reslogo"><img src="'.catch_that_image().'"/></div>';
    endwhile; endif; 
    echo '</div>';    
} 
?>
```

I tried to put: `('cat=restaurants'.'limit=7')` but she no work. How did i go wrong? any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be:

```
$newsposts = new WP_Query('cat=restaurant&posts_per_page=7');
```

Another way to write it (helps readability with larger queries) would be:

```
$newsposts = new WP_Query(array(
    'cat' => 'restaurant',
    'posts_per_page' => 7,
));
```

See [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) in Codex for description of available parameters.

PS would be good practice to add `wp_reset_postdata()` at the end. You are (correctly) not modifying main query, but you do change global `$post` variable with this loop.

Comment: Hi Rarst, thank you for your help. It makes sense - so by adding the ampersandis how I can add more conditions. I also now have a better understanding of the array key value pair. I've added your wp_reset_postdata() and will do so going forward. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

That's what works for me (showposts):

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
        'showposts' => 4, 
        'post_type' => 'xxx',
        'cache_results' => false
    ));
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have a slight error here, the 'cat' paramater only accepts a post ID as an Integer

Source: [`WP_Query` Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters)